# A hard Cubic Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This problem is from an Olympiad handout:

> Show that there exists infinitely many integer triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that 
>   $ x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz=1$.

I tried to plug $x=y$ and use tangent lines to find solutions inductively, but the method didn't work well. (It gave $(1,1,1) \rightarrow (13,13,-23)$ ,but after that there was only rational roots)

Also I plugged the equation in the cubic formula and tried to delete the cubic root, but it also failed.

Help me please :I

Comment: You might find something to note at http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa73/aa7331.pdf

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079816908600148).

Comment: There are infinitely many rational solutions using an elliptic curve. However, the [cubic Pell](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500750/on-the-cubic-pell-equation-x3dy3d2z3-3dxyz-1-for-d-23-etc) has form, $$x^3+dy^3+d^2z^3-3dxyz = 1$$ which is not the form of your equation, so it may be doubtful it has infinitely many integer solutions. And a quick computer search doesn't find even find "smallish" others except those already given.

Comment: @user496634 Can you elaborate some? I don't get it :(

Comment: Sorry; I misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution, but it's a start. Take modulo $x$, so $y^3+z^3\equiv1$. Set $y^3+z^3=ax+1$. Similarly, set $x^3+z^3=by+1$ and $x^3+y^3=cz+1$. Then $$x^3+y^3+z^3=\tfrac12(ax+by+cz+3).$$
Now express $2xyz$ in terms of $(a,b,c)$ by solving the three simultaneous equations. Namely,
$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac12(-ax+by+cz+1)}$
And similarly for the other variables, so
$2xyz=\sqrt[3]{(-ax+by+cz+1)(ax-by+cz+1)(ax+by-cz+1)},$
Noting that the factor of $2$ cancels out. Now the expression inside the root must be a perfect cube. Maybe you can try continuing from here?

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below,

$x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz=1$

Along with numerical solutions shown above $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1) = (13,13,-23)$ there is also the solution $ (x,y,z)=( (468/659), (468/659), (-205/659 ) )$