# For what $N$ does $N=x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz$ have infinite integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Further to this question, [A hard Cubic Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656902/a-hard-cubic-diophantine-equation) I considered the more general equation $N=x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz$.

As $x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz$ is homogenous, any solution $(N_0,x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to $x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz=N$ gives a set of solutions $(k^3N_0,kx_0,ky_0,kz_0)$.

In particular, any solution with positive $N$ gives a solution for $-N$ using $k=-1$, so it’s not necessary to further consider negative $N$

For example, $(N,x,y,z)=(13,-3,2,2)$ gives $(-13,3,-2,-2)$

Clearly, $(x,y,z)$ are interchangeable.

Using a small search up to $N=152$ I’ve found, with $a,b,k$ integer, just

$$(N,x,y,z)=(0,-a,0,a)$$

$$(N,x,y,z)=(19k^3,(-b-1)k,3k,(b-1)k)$$

**Examples as $(N,x,y,z)$**

$$(0,-45,0,45)$$
$$(19,-6,3,4)$$
$$(152,-12,6,8)$$

I’ve noticed other $N$ that seem possible candidates, but haven’t spotted the patterns. For example,

$$(9,-1575,583,1163)$$
$$(9,-944,522,545)$$
$$(9,-703,-198,838)$$
$$(9,-323,-187,457)$$
$$(9,-167,80,108)$$
$$(9,-162,86,97)$$
$$(9,-47,-34,72)$$
$$(9,-7,4,4)$$
$$(9,-2,1,2)$$
$$(9,0,1,2)$$
$$(9,1,2,2)$$

Other $N$ values that look interesting are $6,17,33,37,48,51,72,93,96,107,114,117,136$

**My question:**

Apart from $0$ and numbers of the form $19k^3$, for what $N$ does $N=x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz$ have infinite integer solutions?

**Update 5th March 2018**

I’m also interested in:

values of $N$ where all solutions are known

values of $N$ where it can be shown that there are a finite number of solutions

values of $N$ where it can be shown that there no solutions.

Comment: The equation $x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz=9$ curiously has a lot of integer solutions. What were the search bounds used?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I looked in the range $-3000$ to $3000$. The other $N$ I note as interesting are much the same. Up to $N=152$, without counting them all, $117$ perhaps has the most with $21$ solutions. Please let me know if you wish me to include these, or other, results within my question.

Comment: The case $N=9$ will do for now. The situation is reminiscent to [the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584378/parametric-solutions-to-x3y3z3-n) $x^3+y^3+z^3 =N$ where some (like $N=792$) have many integer solutions, but is not known if there is infinitely many.

Comment: I think the general equation is $x^3+y^3+z^3+Mxyz = N$ where my post is $M=0$ while yours is $M=-2$. It seems general results are not yet known.

Comment: Do you still have the data for $N=117 = 9\times13$? Can you include it (not necessarily in Latex form) in the post? We might now know better how to spot a pattern, if any.

Comment: No pattern yet? Perhaps just post the results here. Maybe the community can find something.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III some results shown as a answer. Sorry for the delay,

Comment: Hmm, with 20 solutions for $N = 117$, I assumed there would be a pattern but it is harder to ascertain than I thought.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III I’ve found the last solution in the previously used range. If you want further solutions, I need info to speed up the search. Can you see any way to express one variable in terms of the other two? Perhaps range restristions of $y,z$ given $x$?

Comment: I tried to find one variable in terms of the other two, like what Bailey and I did for $x^3+y^3+z^3 = (z+1)^3$, but the proper substitution eludes me for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the above equation shown below:

$N=x^3+y^3+z^3-2xyz$

Seiji Tomita has given an identity on his web site:

http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat

Click on the link "Computational number theory" & then select article #264.

His identity is $x^3+y^3+z^3-n(xyz)=(n^3-27)$

where $(x,y,z)=(m,n-m,-3)$

For $n=2$ we have,

$(-m)^3+(m-2)^3+3^3-2(m)(2-m)(3)=19$

Since $m$ can take infinite values, then $N = 19$ can take on infinite integer solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer, which I’ve upvoted. I think my questions already shows $19k^3$ as an answer, but Seiji Tomita’s identity provides a solution to more general problem.

Comment: @OldPeter Here is [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839649/when-does-ab-sqrt-n3a-b-sqrt-n3-c3-have-integer-solutions-a-b-c-n) on computational mathematics you might find interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Updated 20/1/24 with “$-2171$” solution. Search in range $-3000$ to $3000$

Too big for a comment

As requested, some solutions for $N=117$

I don’t have the original results, and there are unexpected and unusual problems with my 2018 program, but here some small solutions.

(x,y,z)=

(-2171,-704 ,2654),

(-1964 ,653 ,1508),

(-1404 ,173 ,1288),

(-1331 ,449 ,1017),

(-773 ,-351 ,1019),

(-878 ,-106 ,949),

(-560,173,440),

(-353,-289,569),

(-202,-107,278),

(-91,-44,122),

(-91,40,62),

(-62,-52,101),

(-59,25,41),

(-43,-36,70),

(-27 ,10 ,20 ),

(-18 ,-11 ,26 ),

(-11 ,-4 ,14 ),

(-11 ,2 ,10 ),

(-2 ,0 ,5 ),

(1 ,1 ,5 ),

(2 ,4 ,5 )